# Passing Expectation into Series (specifically Sine)

Tags: probability, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

I want to show that this is true:

$${ \mathbb{E}\big[\sin X_t \big]} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n}{ \mathbb{E}\big[ X_t^{2n+1} \big]}}{(2n+1)!}$$
($X_t$ is a Brownian Motion).

By linearity I can pass the expectation to each term in the series. Since each term contains only one variable, $X_t$, I can pull out the constants from the expectation.

Comment: Lebesgue series theorem tells you conditions ensuring that $$\int\sum_nf_n=\sum_n\int f_n.$$ Apply it.

Comment: .......Perfect.